# Why GameObject in Unity starts moving when i add rigidbody and only rotate it in script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I rotate GameObject by moving mouse, when i added rigidbody GameObject started moving in forward direction, why does it move?

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMover : MonoBehaviour
{
private Vector2 _mouseInput;
private Vector2 _rotation;

private void Start()
{
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    Cursor.visible = false;
}

private void Update()
{
    CalculateRotation();

    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(_rotation.x, _rotation.y, 0);
}

private void CalculateRotation()
{
    _mouseInput.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X");
    _mouseInput.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y");

    _rotation.y += _mouseInput.x;
    _rotation.x -= _mouseInput.y;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RigidBody and I quote

> Adding a Rigidbody component to an object will put its motion under the control of Unity's physics engine. Even without adding any code, a Rigidbody object will be pulled downward by gravity and will react to collisions with incoming objects if the right Collider component is also present.

Does this unswer you question ? to be honest if you just read the documentation you'll find out , adding rigidbody to a gameobject is like giving an object the features of real-life (gravity , movement , force etc).

Comment: Yes thanks i got it, the problem was that GameObject bent over and moved in this direction, because i rotate it in X coordinate, so i freezed it in GameObject and rotate Camera in X coordinate.